# scp with system user?

Tags: ssh, user-accounts, login, scp

I have a user that was created this way:

`sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/someone --group someone`

This user does not have login, but when I login to server with my own user, I can change to that user using `sudo su - someone -s /bin/bash`. And it is OK.

But sometimes I need to transfer files remotely to `someone` user home directory, but I can't use that user because it does not have a login. The long way is to `scp` files to my own home directory, then login with my own user, then change to `someone` and copy those files from my home directory to `someone` home directory. But that is very annoying to do it.

Maybe there is some better alternative where I could directly `scp` files using `someone` user?

Comment: what do you mean by **This user does not have login**?  does  `adduser` not add to the `/etc/passwd` file?  did you try giving the added user a random string password?

Comment: @Skaperen "This is a “system” user. It is there to own and run the application, it isn’t supposed to be a person type user with a login etc. In Ubuntu, a system user gets a UID below 1000, has no shell (it’s actually /bin/false) and has logins disabled" at least thats what I read.

Comment: So if you want to log in as that user, give it a password and a shell and create its home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add users with a shell that will only allow utilities such as `scp`, `rsync` and other nice utilities: [rssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rssh)

I used it on my webhosting service way back, and it did the trick. Users were unable to log in and get a shell, but they were still able to upload stuff properly.

Add them as normal users, but give them rssh as a shell with chsh, and you're good. That way, you can easily upload files as their users, or let them upload themselves.

Comment: Can you provide rssh.conf example how to configure it so that `no login` user could `scp` to his owned directory?

Comment: @Andrius I haven't used it in ages, but if I remember correctly, no configuration is required, as that's what it does by default. Just make sure that the users in question has `rssh` set as their shell, instead of `nologin`. You can check (or even change) this directly in /etc/passwd